# Selenium problems getting content in headless mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver

I have a class, a partial implementation is presented below:

```rb
  class Browser
    CHROME_OPTIONS = %w[
      --headless=new
      --window-size=1920,1080
      --start-maximized
      --no-sandbox
      --blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false
      --disable-gpu
      --hide-scrollbars
      --mute-audio
      --enable-automation
      --disable-web-security
      --disable-session-crashed-bubble
      --disable-breakpad
      --disable-sync
      --no-first-run
      --use-mock-keychain
      --keep-alive-for-test
      --disable-popup-blocking
      --disable-extensions
      --disable-hang-monitor
      --disable-features=site-per-process,IsolateOrigins,TranslateUI
      --disable-translate
      --disable-background-networking
      --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess
      --disable-background-timer-throttling
      --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows
      --disable-client-side-phishing-detection
      --disable-default-apps
      --disable-dev-shm-usage
      --disable-ipc-flooding-protection
      --disable-prompt-on-repost
      --disable-renderer-backgrounding
      --force-color-profile=srgb
      --metrics-recording-only
      --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update
      --password-store=basic
      --ignore-certificate-errors
    ]

    def initialize
      @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, {
        options: Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(args: CHROME_OPTIONS)
      }
    end

    delegate :get, :current_url, :title, :execute_script, :quit, to: :@driver
  end
```

Which I use to get content from pages. The problem is that for the site: https://techdocs.akamai.com/home I can't get content in headless mode, although everything works fine in normal mode and for other sites.

I tried experimenting with different headless settings, headless=old ..., used additional browser settings to get content, but nothing gave the expected result.

Maybe someone has faced a similar problem.

```
selenium-webdriver (4.12.0)

Google Chrome 117.0.5938.88
```

Comment: Move to WATIR and post your questions there. That's the wrapper around Ruby Selenium Binding.